# permute a d-dimensional tensor in C

Tags: c, arrays

I am interested in permuting the elements of a d-dimensional tensor using C code (and hence, using loops only) and I would like to write the function with d as an argument. 
The tensor data is so far contained in a "d-dimensional" pointer (for example, a simple array when d = 1). So far, I have defined this pointer statically with **T for d = 2, although indications were given here for a dynamic approach: [Create a d-dimensional pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34398562/create-a-d-dimensional-pointer). 
How to write the code with d as argument without using a (dirty) if loop:

```
if (d == 2) { 
specific code for permuting
} 
else if (d == 3) { 
other specific code
}
```

? 
Note that the permutation order is an input to the function. 
Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** It seems I misinterpreted the question. However the below answer is still relevant to the topic, so I am not going to remove it for now.

The answer could be specific to the problem, perhaps the code for permuting `d == 2` can be reduced to the same as `d == 3`. I don't know exactly what the code would look like as I have not studied tensors, but if it is not reducible then the "dirty" method that you have is your best option.

Alternatively, if you have the number of dimensions `#define`d similar to the pointer representation in the post you link, you could use pre-processor directives to turn on/off extra loops. This should give you a bit more condensed code. it should probably look like:

```
#define D 4 // Number of dimensions to use
#define MAX_D 10 // maximum # of dimensions
...
#if D >= MAX_D 
for(int i = 0; i < dimensions[MAX_D - 1]; i++) {
#endif
...
#if D >= 2
for(int i = 0; i < dimensions[1]; i++) {
#endif
// Base case ; D == 1
for(int i = 0; i < dimensions[0]; i++) {
    // Permutation stuff here
}
#if D == 2
}
#elif D == 3
}}
#elif D == 4
}}}
....
#endif
```

While this is a bit ugly, it prevents you from having to create and maintain a bunch of different versions.

---

The link provided is really the best approach for creating a d-dimensional pointed in C. However, you can simulate a d-dimensional array with a 1-D array and a bit of math.

You can use the following functions to achieve this:

```
void get(int *d_dimens, int d, size_t *dimensions, size_t *point, int val) {
    size_t index = 0; // Index of the number
    size_t dim = 1; // Location of the current dimension
    for(int i = 0; i < d; i++) {
        index += point[i] * dim;
        dim *= dimensions[i];
    }
    return d_dimens[index];
}

void set(int *d_dimens, int d, size_t *dimensions, size_t *point, int val) {
    size_t index = 0; // Index of the number
    size_t dim = 1; // Location of the current dimension
    for(int i = 0; i < d; i++) {
        index += point[i] * dim;
        dim *= dimensions[i];
    }
    d_dimens[index] = val;
}

int *create(int d, size_t *dimensions) {
    sizt_t num_elems = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < d; i++)
        num_elems *= dimensions[i];
    int *ptr = malloc(sizeof (int) * num_elems);
    return ptr;
}
```

Where `dimensions` is an array of dimensions, `d_dimens` is the 1-D array we are using to simulate a d-D array, and `d` is the number of dimensions. For example if you want a 4x5x2 array, you would use `dimensions = {4, 5, 2}; d = 3;`

Comment: This does not appear to address the question of how to permutate the tensor. Also you may want to use `size_t` for indexes.

Comment: Yeah, I misinterpreted the question the first time around. I think I fixed it, thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. I think writing the C code for permuting with the dimension as input to the function is related to whether I can do it with loops using any language. For example, if the dimension is 2, two loops do the transpose operation. If the dimension is 3, I need three loops embedded in one another. How to parametrize the number of loops as input of the function and still fill the cube?

Answer (score 0):

> So far, I have defined this pointer statically with **T for d = 2, although indications were given here for a dynamic approach: …

I recommend not using multidimensional pointers unless sparse storage is needed. Instead, see this nicely illustrated answer to the question [How does NumPy's transpose() method permute the axes of an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32034565/2413201) As explained there, with this scheme the tensor values don't even need to be copied for the transpose operation.